# how to enter url having two forward slashes in it

Tags: python, url, escaping, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I am entering an url to process a file and return me an api with an output example: 12.334.198.190:5000/home/files/xyx.pdf and in my linux vm the address of the file is /home/files/xyz.pdf so the error is 'No such file or directory: home/files/xyz.pdf'. I think the '/' before home is not being picked up and thus the error. Any idea how to fix this?
Adding code for reference:

```
import ectd
from ectd import convert
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
#from flask.views import MethodView

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)   
class ectdtext(Resource):
    def get(self, result):
        return {'data': ectd.convert(result)}

#api.add_resource(ectdtext, '/ectd/<result>')
#categorie

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def get_dir(path):
    categories = convert(path)
    return categories

#@app.route('/get_dir/<path>')
#def get_dir(path):
#    return path

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the configuration of the webserver in your VM.

Comment: My understanding is there needs to be a forwardslash after the port number and one more before home/files.. How do I enter it in that way in the url or do I need to escape something in my code?

Comment: Maybe you should show your code.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 added code. please check

Comment: What does that Python script have to do with getting PDF files?

Comment: The python script has a convert function that takes the path of a pdf file to process it and predict the category of that file